# how do I set routes on debian 12 to use wlan0 for internet and eth0 for a local subnet

Tags: linux, routes, tcp

I am unable to set up routes so that the systems in my network will communicate properly.
all wifi adapters are connected to a dhcp server that delivers 10.9.32.x ip addresses.
all 1gb ethernet adapters are manually assigned to addresses in range 192.168.0.1 - 192.168.0.5.
the route tables look like this:

```
sudo route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.9.32.254     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp0s20f3
10.9.32.0       10.9.32.78      255.255.255.0   UG    300    0        0 wlp0s20f3
10.9.32.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp0s20f3
192.168.0.0     192.168.0.1     255.255.255.0   UG    600    0        0 enx00e04c0c0736

ip route
default via 10.9.32.254 dev wlp0s20f3 proto dhcp src 10.9.32.78 metric 600 
10.9.32.0/24 via 10.9.32.78 dev wlp0s20f3 src 10.9.32.78 metric 300 
10.9.32.0/24 dev wlp0s20f3 proto kernel scope link src 10.9.32.78 metric 600 
192.168.0.0/24 via 192.168.0.1 dev enx00e04c0c0736 src 192.168.0.1 metric 600
```

I added this route manually: 10.9.32.0/24 via 10.9.32.78 with a lower metric to see if that would help, but it does the same thing if that route is removed.

I can communicate without any problems to the nodes on 192.168.0.0 and the internet, but if I try to communicate to the nodes on the 10.9.32.x, there are problems. If I try to send a udp or tcpip packet to a node on 10.9.32.x, it doesn't get there. If I traceroute to a node on on 192.168.0.x it returns in ~800 msecs, but if I traceroute to any node on 10.9.32.x it returns in 3 seconds.

```
sudo traceroute tvproj
traceroute to tvproj (192.168.0.2), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  tvproj (192.168.0.2)  0.842 ms  0.807 ms  0.793 ms

sudo traceroute w-tvproj
traceroute to w-tvproj (10.9.32.134), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  w-ole (10.9.32.78)  3055.638 ms !H  3055.610 ms !H  3055.609 ms !H
```

I have set up tcpdump captures on the target nodes and I can see the packets that use 192.168.0.x for tcpip and udp, but I get nothing when I use the 10.9.32.x addresses.

If anyone could assist or point me to a place that explains how to set up the routes properly, I would greatly appreciate it.
Thanks,
Ole Jensen.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Barmar - sorry about that, I will move the question to one of those forums.

Answer (score 0):

```
ip route
default via 10.9.32.254 dev wlp0s20f3 proto dhcp src 10.9.32.78 metric 600 
10.9.32.0/24 via 10.9.32.78 dev wlp0s20f3 src 10.9.32.78 metric 300 
10.9.32.0/24 dev wlp0s20f3 proto kernel scope link src 10.9.32.78 metric 600
```

Access to 10.9.32.0/24 is already covered by this line:

```
10.9.32.0/24 dev wlp0s20f3 proto kernel scope link src 10.9.32.78 metric 600
```

so you don't need any other route to access any ressources in 10.9.32.0/24.

Btw, why `via 10.9.32.78` ? Is that a router or the device you're trying to access?
A `route via xx.xx.xx.xx` is use when you need to send traffic a router/gateway for a specific IP or subnet.

If you can't access 10.9.32.0/24 it might be because you Wifi Access-Point is configured with client isolation which prevent Wifi client from talking to each other. You need to check that. In that case, you may want to remove the `10.9.32.0/24 dev wlp0s20f3 proto kernel scope link src 10.9.32.78 metric 600` route to force the traffic to go trought the default gateway at `10.9.32.254`.

A nice tool to troubleshoot route is to use `ip route get`, i.e `ip route get 10.9.32.78`. It will show you what route it's trying to use.

Comment: Maiko - Thanks for your response. I tried your suggestions and it still doesn't work. Thanks for the tip about "ip route get". I will pursue that. Due to the message from Barmar saying that this is the wrong place for the question, I will repost the question in another forum.